# Monitor a page for any updates

Tags: feature-request

I want to keep track of few pages if there is any new answer or comment posted by any user to the specific question in that page.
While i was answering questions, I found the question was interesting and want to check for the best answers for it. I can make it favourite and keep track of it. But i find 100+ pages like this. So every day visiting each page for any updates is tedious job.
Is there any feature available to monitor for updates in the specified pages ?
I request for `monitor` as a link, which updates for any changes in the specified pages.

Comment: After a week, you are trying to monitor 700 questions? After a month, 3000? Doesn't it seem like that would get very tedious to decipher and further generate excessive traffic for the exchange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just favorite it (click on the star), and your profiles favorite-tab will highlight any question+answers which changed since you last looked.

Answer (score 6):

What about the question's RSS feed? You can use it with your preferred reader.

The link of this question's feed is:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/285651

Comment: I just want to check the updates in SO only.. I don't think it is the appropriate solution. Now i got update of your answer because i posted a question.. similar to that, for the questions i don't post also, i want updates... that is monitor feature i mean...

Comment: The RSS feed is question based, so all updates to a question you get 'notified' of. You can add as much questions in your RSS reader as you like.